# I can't identify the database name on DB2 using Squirrel

Tags: db2, talend, squirrel-sql

I want to create a connection from Talend but i coudn't identify the databse name and the schema name , I am using Squierrel client.

---

I changed  the database name like  on squierrel but I still have the same problem. 
I think this because the structure of data on DB2 , tables are considered as objects and i can't identify the name of database  of this objects

Comment: This is not a real question nor the right way to pose a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the alias for the connection in SQuirreL you should see the database name in the URL for the JDBC connection.

It should look something like `jdbc:db2:my_db`.